# How to open previous fragment when we are switching from one fragment to another using addToBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two Fragments - A and B.

When I replace Fragment A with Fragment B, how do you go back to Fragment A from Fragment B without adding or replacing Fragment A again?

Comment: just press the back button :) do you want to load it programmatically...?

Comment: You want to press a button? instead of back button?

Comment: When i am replacing fragment how to add replaced fragment into addToBackStack() so that i can use popBackSatck();

Comment: @ManjuKumari no way to do it, you need to  manually call addbackstack agian to ur fragment A

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack

Comment: When i am replacing fragment how to add replaced fragment into addToBackStack() so that i can use popBackSatck();

Answer (score 1):

I always use popbackstackimmediage.

Using support library inside class extending fragment(Api <11):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();//returns a boolean
```

For api level >11 inside class extending fragment:

```
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();//returns a boolean
```

For class extending activity you dont need getActivity() context:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();//similar for support library
```

Comment: Quick question, is this in any way better than just calling getActivity().onBackPressed();?

Comment: @Zhuinden onBackPresssed is an interface on the activity. It is needed to be implemented on the activity the fragment is in. These methods produce similar results see @ Golu answer. I just find my answer flexible and generic as it can be used in onBackPressed or any click events(everywhere with valid context).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, the Activity can redefine onBackPressed() and then things will be different.